# Covariance of Log-Normal Variables

Tags: lognormal

In [Obstfeld and Rogoff](http://www.nber.org/papers/w7313.pdf) (2000), formula (12) states the following:

$$ W = (\frac{\phi}{\phi-1}) \frac{E\{K(L^\nu)\}}{E\{\frac{L}{P}C^{-\rho}\}} $$

where $\phi$, $\rho$ and $\nu$ are parameters, $E$ is the expectation operator, and $K$, $L$, $P$,$C$ are endogenous variables jointly log-normally distributed.

They state that given the log-normality it is equivalent to write equation (12) as:

$$ W = (\frac{\phi}{\phi-1}) \frac{E\{K\}E\{L\}^{\nu-1})}{E\{C\}^{-\rho} E\{ \frac{1}{P} \}     } \exp{\psi} $$

where:

$$\psi = \frac{\nu(\nu-1)}{2} \sigma_l^2 - \frac{\rho(\rho+1)}{2} \sigma_c^2  + \nu \sigma_{kl} + \rho \sigma_{cl}  - \rho \sigma_{cp} + \sigma_{lp} $$

I tried to derive the expression for psi, I get something slightly different:

$$\psi = \frac{\nu}{2} \sigma_l^2 - \frac{\rho}{2} \sigma_c^2  + \nu \sigma_{kl} + \rho \sigma_{cl}  - \rho \sigma_{cp} + \sigma_{lp} $$

I don't understand where those extra terms come from.

Any help?

Comment: Is $\sigma_{kl}$ the co-variance between $K$ and $L$?

Comment: Yes, indeed. And $\sigma_{lp}$ is the covariance between $L$ and $P$ and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
E(K) &= E\big(\exp(\ln K) \big)\\
&=\exp\Big(E(\ln K) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma_k^2 \Big),\\
E(L) &= E\big(\exp(\ln L) \big)\\
&=\exp\Big(E(\ln L) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma_l^2 \Big),\\
E\Big(\frac{1}{P}\Big) &= E\big(\exp(-\ln P) \big)\\
&=\exp\Big(-E(\ln P) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma_p^2 \Big), 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
E(C) &= E\big(\exp(\ln C) \big)\\
&=\exp\Big(E(\ln C) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma_c^2 \Big).
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
E(K L^{\nu}) &= E\Big(\exp\big(\ln K + \nu \ln L\big) \Big)\\
&=\exp\Big(E(\ln K) + v E(\ln L)+ \frac{1}{2}\sigma_k^2 + \frac{1}{2} \nu^2\sigma_l^2 + \nu \sigma_{kl}\Big)\\
&= \exp\Big(E(\ln K) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma_k^2 + \nu \Big(E(\ln L)+ \frac{1}{2} \sigma_l^2\Big) + \frac{1}{2}(\nu^2-\nu)\sigma_l^2 + \nu \sigma_{kl}\Big)\\
&= E(K)(E(L))^{\nu}\exp\Big( \frac{1}{2}\nu(\nu-1)\sigma_l^2 + \nu \sigma_{kl} \Big).
\end{align*}
Moreover, 
\begin{align*}
E\left( \frac{L}{P}C^{-\rho} \right) &= E\Big(\exp\big(\ln L - \ln P - \rho \ln C \big) \Big)\\
&= \exp\Big(E(\ln L) - E(\ln P) - \rho E(\ln C) \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad +\frac{1}{2}\sigma_l^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sigma_p^2 + \frac{1}{2}\rho^2\sigma_c^2 - \sigma_{lp} - \rho \sigma_{cl} +\rho\sigma_{cp}\Big)\\
&=\exp\Big(E(\ln L) +\frac{1}{2}\sigma_l^2 - E(\ln P) +\frac{1}{2}\sigma_p^2 - \rho E(\ln C) - \rho \frac{1}{2}\sigma_c^2 \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad + \frac{1}{2}\big(\rho^2+\rho\big)\sigma_c^2 - \sigma_{lp} - \rho \sigma_{cl} +\rho\sigma_{cp}\Big)\\
&= E(L)E\Big(\frac{1}{P}\Big)(E(C))^{-\rho} \exp\Big(\frac{1}{2}\big(\rho^2+\rho\big)\sigma_c^2 - \sigma_{lp} - \rho \sigma_{cl} +\rho\sigma_{cp}\Big).
\end{align*}
Consequently,
\begin{align*}
\frac{E(K L^{\nu})}{E\Big( \frac{L}{P}C^{-\rho} \Big)}&=\frac{E(K)(E(L))^{\nu-1}}{E\Big(\frac{1}{P}\Big)(E(C))^{-\rho}}\\
&\qquad\qquad \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\nu(\nu-1)\sigma_l^2 - \frac{1}{2}\big(\rho^2+\rho\big)\sigma_c^2 + \nu \sigma_{kl} + \rho \sigma_{cl} -\rho\sigma_{cp} +\sigma_{lp}\right).
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
\psi = \frac{1}{2}\nu(\nu-1)\sigma_l^2 - \frac{1}{2}\rho\big(\rho+1\big)\sigma_c^2 + \nu \sigma_{kl} + \rho \sigma_{cl} -\rho\sigma_{cp} +\sigma_{lp}.
\end{align*}